# Swift: Can I load Url data inside a collection/table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a horizontal scrolling collection view inside a UITableView cell, achieving the view same as that of Netflix.

**Currently, I am loading URL data in my view controller containing table view and passing the array of data in UITableViewCell which contains the collectionView, and then rendering collection view cells.**

But I'm feeling lack of controls using this method. For e.g, UI management, hiding, showing views depending on URL data load and error, etc.

> I tried loading URL data inside table view cell and that works
>   perfectly fine for me but I don't think that's appropriate to do, as
>   only controllers should control everything.

The closure I'm using to load data in my controller is -

```
private func fetchData() {
    let id = UserDefaults.standard.getUserId()
    Service.shared.fetch(userId: id) { (data, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.5, execute: {
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
                return
            }
            let result = data?.count != 0 ? "Success" : "Failure"

            switch result {
            case ResultType.Failure.rawValue:
                print("Failure")
            case ResultType.Success.rawValue:
                if let data = data {
                    self.data = data
                }
            default: break
            }
        })
    }
}
```

> Back to the Question, Is it fine loading the data inside
>   UITableViewCell in order to hide/show or animate UICollectionView inside that UITableViewCell?

Moreover, Assume a scenario where I have to load 4-5 URL data and render them in each custom table view cell which may or may not contain a collection view.

Complicated!

Comment: Yes, it's bad idea to load data or do some logic in UITableViewCell.

Comment: @IBAction Thanks for helping me with nothing!

Answer (score 1):

You can load data in a view, but it wouldn’t be a good architecture. It hampers reusabilty and mixes responsibilities. Also, table view cells will be reused, which will eventually lead to weird data loading behavior and probably bugs.

I suggest extracting data loading into a custom class, and using that class in the view controller. This way your data loading is decoupled from the controller and the view, giving the most flexibility.